# print all values of a file after removing some characters using grep

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a file in which the values are stored as below.

```
Assistant Professor at SASTRA University
St John's memorial college
Paul George Univeristy
Department Chair at University of Texas
```

I am extracting all the characters after the first **at** using the below command.

```
grep -o ' at .*$' checkin.txt | cut -c5-
```

Now, I am trying to get the output as,

```
SASTRA University
St John's memorial college
Paul George University
University of Texas
```

This is the script I have.

```
while read -r line; do
echo $line
done < <( grep -o ' at .*$' checkin.txt | cut -c5- )
```

However, the script gives me the below output.

```
SASTRA University
University of Texas
```

How can I extract all the values?

Comment: It really would be much easier if you posted one question showing your initial input and final output. I appreciate the effort you are putting into each question and that's great but we could have solved the whole thing in one go which would have been better for you.

Comment: @Terdon, Sorry for posting multiple questions. I thought if I split into multiple questions, it would be easier for viewing the question. Anyways, I will keep this in mind and post as a single question from next time.

Comment: Don't worry about it, seriously, I can see the effort you put into making your questions clear and I appreciate it. It would just be much easier for you and also, it would help us understand the whole problem. Asking for small pieces of the puzzle like this is likely to lead to [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that not all lines have `at`. Try this instead:

```
$ sed 's/.* at //'  file 
SASTRA University
St John's memorial college
Paul George Univeristy
University of Texas
```

If you can have mutiple `at`s, use Perl instead:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.+? at //' file
```

Comment: Saw you answered after I hit, post it. Deleting my almost identical A. Thanks for the edit BTW, earlier today!

Comment: @slm great minds :) and you're very welcome.

Comment: @terdon, It prints all the lines correctly. But in lines that have more than one "at", it takes the last at and gives me the value only after the last at.

Comment: @Ramesh see updated answer.